# Is there an importation missing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am facing a problem with importation because I've created a div input as a component to use in other pages. In this case, sign up page:

```
<Input 
                    placeholder="Email"
                    name="email"
                    {...register("email")}
 />
```

But, this input is not receiving this register as a component.

```
import { InputContainer } from "./styles"

    function Input({placeholder, register, name, error, ...rest}) {
        return (
            <InputContainer isErrored={!!error}>
                <input 
                    placeholder={placeholder} 
                    {...register(name)}
                    {...rest} />
            </InputContainer>
        )
    }
    export default Input
```

I've received that register is not a function, but I had declared it before, on signup page too:

```
const {
        register, 
        handleSubmit,
        formState: { errors },
    } = useForm({
        resolver:yupResolver(schema)
    })
```

Comment: can you please attach the code of `register`

Comment: You're not passing `register={…}` to `Input`. You are spreading the return value of `register('email')`. Just remove the `register` and `name` props from the `Input` component  and only rely on the `rest`.